# npm install Permission denied /.npm/_cacache/

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install

When I use sudo npm install command get error.

```
usr6783@usr6783:~/albarakaMobil/client/mobile-branch$ sudo npm install
[sudo] password for usr6783: 
npm WARN deprecated react-native-languages@1.0.7: This project has been renamed to react-native-localize. Install using react-native-localize  instead.
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated sw-precache@5.2.1: Please migrate to Workbox: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-sw
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm WARN deprecated sw-toolbox@3.6.0: Please migrate to Workbox: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-sw
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.5 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.3.3: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.2: I wrote this module a very long time ago; you should use something else.
npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.10: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an import issue introduced in 2.1.0
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --mirror -q git://github.com/rhdeck/react-native-fix-xcode-10.git /home/usr6783/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-aa7d6ae5/.git
npm ERR! /home/usr6783/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-aa7d6ae5/.git: Permission denied
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/usr6783/.npm/_logs/2019-05-07T06_12_46_865Z-debug.log
```

Comment: See: "**Permission denied**"

Comment: You shouldn't be using `sudo` with npm (even when installing globally). check this guild on how to install `npm`  and resolving eacces permissions errors https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Answer (score 15):

use :

> sudo npm cache clean -f

referred to [this](https://github.com/contentful/contentful.js/issues/211)

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar problem today, and `npm` suggested I should run

```
sudo chown -R 501:20 "~/.npm"
```

It says this is due to a bug in previous versions of `npm` and has since been addressed. You might want to update to `npm` version 7.10.0 or later, and run the command above.